Нужна помощь в переносе кода с php на python, трудность связана с openssl_encrypt
На функцию поступает encryption_password, encryption_iv и словарь с данными.
Трудность заключается с работой openssl_encrypt на php
function encrypt($secret_pw, $secret_iv, $string){
  $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
  $pw = hash('sha256', $secret_pw);
  $iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_iv), 0, 16);
  $output = openssl_encrypt($string, $encrypt_method, $pw, 0, $iv);
  $output = base64_encode($output);
  return $output;
}


Трудность-то в чем?

Те способы, что я находил(интернет, chatgpt) выдавали другой ключ. То есть в openssl_encrypt происходила другая логика.
